# Underlying cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace.

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, centos6.8

I was trying to build spark environment on **CentOS6.8** on **macOS** using VMware Fusion.

I have previously installed **jdk-10.0.1**, **hadoop-2.4.1.tar.gz**, and **MySQL**. They worked successfully.

However, when I was trying to format matadata repository,

```
schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema
```

the following error happened:

```
    which: no hbase in (/opt/hive/bin:/usr/local/hive/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hive/bin:/root/bin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/opt/hive/bin)
     ^HMetastore connection URL:     jdbc:mysql://hbase01:3306/myhive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    Metastore Connection Driver :    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    Metastore connection User:       myhive
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to load driver
    Underlying cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace.
    *** schemaTool failed ***
```

I ignored it and entered "$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive", the following error happened:

```
which: no hbase in (/opt/hive/bin:/usr/local/hive/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hive/bin:/root/bin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/opt/hive/bin)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:363)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:663)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

I am sure that I have put the mysql-connector-java into the lib folder of hive. But still there is something wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Underlying cause:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

The above error shows that you have to  mysql.jdbc.driver jar is missing.

- Download the mysql JDBC Connector to access the MySQL database from Metastore Service.
- Place the connector jar to $HIVE_HOME/lib directory to make it available in classpath.

> ```
> wget http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.7-bin.jar.zip
> unzip mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.7-bin.jar.zip cp
> mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.7-bin.jar  $HIVE_HOME/lib/
> ```

- Create Database and User with proper access rights
- MySQL is installed. Run the below command to access the mysql prompt.

> sudo mysql

- Now execute below commands on mysql prompt to configure hive user and metastore schema in MySQL.

> Create database hive DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8; mysql> grant all
> PRIVILEGES on *.* TO 'hive'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY
> 'password_for_hive' WITH GRANT OPTION;

- In above command, in place of localhost you can use IP Address or hostname of the Metastore Server.
- Configure Hive to work with MySQL
  gedit $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml
- Add the following configurations to the end of the line.

```
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive</value>
    <description>JDBC connection string used by Hive Metastore</description>
  </property>
 
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>JDBC Driver class</description>
  </property>
 
  <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
      <value>hive</value>
      <description>Metastore database user name</description>
  </property>
 
  <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>password_hive</value>
      <description>Metastore database password</description>
  </property>
 
  <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
      <value>thrift://localhost:9084</value>
      <description>Thrift server hostname and port</description>
  </property>
```

- Save the file and close it
- In above configurations, you can use relevant IP Address or host name in place of localhost.
- Change the value of properties of hive-site.xml

  hive.exec.scratchdir
        /home/path/to/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/iotmp
        HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission. For each connecting user, an HDFS scratch dir: ${hive.exec.scratchdir}/<username> is created, with ${hive.scratch.dir.permission}.
      
    hive.exec.local.scratchdir
        /home/path/to/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/iotmp
        Local scratch space for Hive jobs

  ```
  <property>
    <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
    <value>/home/path/to/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/iotmp</value>
    <description>Temporary local directory for added resources in the remote file system.</description>
  </property>
  ```
- Edit the hive-env.sh file and add the following

> export METASTORE_PORT=9084

- Start Hive Metastore Server
- Initialize the Hive Metastore database schema:

> HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType $databaseType $ hive
> --service metastore &

- start hive

> hive

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works for me. The metastore schema initialized successfully. However, when I went on and entered "hive", the following error happened:                                                                                                `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader`                                      I wonder what can lead to this type of bug

Comment: I have edited the  answer please let me know if you are still facing any issue